# Minecraft 1.10 Monster Spawner Chance to Spawn Varied Mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I mean is--can you spawn in a monster spawner that has a chance to spawn a different mob or type of mob seperate from the mob already being spawned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, monster spawners have a `SpawnPotentials` list, in which multiple different mobs can be specified. Here's an example with a charged creeper and a zombie:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {Delay:-1,SpawnPotentials:[{Weight:1,Entity:{id:"Creeper",powered:1b}},{Weight:1,Entity:{id:"Zombie"}}]}
```

For versions later than 1.10, you'l need to replace `Creeper` with `minecraft:creeper` and `Zombie` with `minecraft:zombie`.

Expanded:

```
{
    Delay:-1,
    SpawnPotentials:
    [
        {
            Weight:2,
            Entity:
            {
                id:"Creeper",
                powered:1b
            }
        },
        {
            Weight:1,
            Entity:
            {
                id:"Zombie"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `SpawnPotentials` contains a list of entries with a `Weight` integer and a `Entity` compound tag.

`Weight` determines how often this type of mob is chosen. In my example, the ratio of creepers to zombies will be 2:1.

`Entity` is where all of the tags for the entity you want to spawn should go, such as their `id` and `powered:1b`.

`Delay:-1` makes the spawner immediately pick at random from its `SpawnPotentials` to copy to `SpawnData`, rather than spawning whatever's in `SpawnData` first (a pig, by default).